# Что использовать для localStorage?

Tags: javascript

Данная страница записывает и удаляет задачи, которые написал пользователь. Я собираюсь сохранять то, что сделал пользователь, с помощью `localStorage`. Но я впал в ступор, не понимаю, как сохранять информацию, в какой структуре данных. Для этого лучше использовать простые объекты или класс? И можно привести пример объекта/класса, который можно использовать для этого?
В данном вопросе я спрашивал по структуре кода, зачем мне использовать классы или объекты. Данный вопрос не является дубликатом вопроса, в котором спрашивают про то, как получить информацию из `localStorage`

```js
let task, tasks, task__close;
let add__button = document.querySelector('.add__button');
let add__input = document.querySelector('.add__input');
let arr = [];
tasks = document.querySelector('.tasks');
task = [...tasks.querySelectorAll('.task')];

function addElem() {
 if (add__input.value === '') {
  return false;
 }
 let block = document.createElement('div');
 block.className = 'task';
 arr = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < task.length; i++) {
  arr.unshift(task[i].getAttribute('data-id'));
 }
 arr.sort(function(a,b){
  return a - b;
 });
 let num = addNext(arr);

 block.setAttribute('data-id', num);
 block.setAttribute('data-listener', false);
 block.innerHTML = '<div class="task__close"></div>';
 block.innerHTML += add__input.value;
 task.unshift(block);
 tasks.prepend(block);
 add__input.value = '';
 startClose();
} // function addElem()

function startClose() {
 task__close = tasks.querySelectorAll('.task__close');
 for (let i = 0; i < task.length; i++) {
  if (task[i].getAttribute('data-listener') == 'false') {
   task__close[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let id = event.path[1].getAttribute('data-id');
    task.splice(id, 1);
    for (let i = 0; i < task.length; i++) {
     task[i].setAttribute('data-id', i);
    }
    event.path[1].remove();
   });
   task[i].setAttribute('data-listener', true);
  }
 }
} // function startClose()

add__button.addEventListener('click', () => {
 addElem();
});

add__input.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
 if (event.code == 'Enter' || event.keyCode == '13' || event.key == 'Enter') {
  addElem();
 }
});

startClose();

function addNext(arr) {
 for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (arr[i] != i) {
   arr.splice(i, 0, i);
   return i;
     }
  }
 arr.push(arr.length);
 return arr.length - 1;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 color: black;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul {
 margin: 0;
}

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

img {
 display: block;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

.container {
 max-width: 1100px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.container.fluid {
 max-width: 100%; 
}

.spheres {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.sphere {
 border-right: 1px solid black;
 flex-grow: 1;
 padding: 15px 0;
}

.sphere:first-child {
 border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.sphere  .svg__icon {
 max-width: 70px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.sphere  .svg__icon img {
 width: 100%;
}

.sphere__title {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 10px;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.add {
 background-color: #46a049;
 padding: 25px 0;
}

.add__title {
 font-size: 22px;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
}

.add__input-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 max-width: 500px;
 margin: 10px auto 0;
 padding: 0 15px;
}

.add__input {
 outline: 0;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-size: inherit;
 border: 1px solid white;
 display: block;
 border-radius: 5px;
 padding: 7px 55px 7px 20px;
 width: 100%;
}

.add__button {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right:15px;
 transform: translate(0, -50%);
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
}

.add__button:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-40%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
 width: 2px;
 background-color: #91a8c4;
 height: 20px;
 right: 40%;
}

.add__button:after {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 top: 50%;
 transform: translate(-40%, -50%);
 width: 2px;
 background-color: #91a8c4;
 height: 20px;
 right: 40%;
}

.add__button:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.add__button:hover:before {
 background-color: #3675bc;
}

.add__button:hover:after {
 background-color: #3675bc;
}

.tasks {
 margin-top: 20px;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

.task {
 position: relative;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
 padding: 10px 0;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
}

.task__close {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 border: 1px solid gray;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-right: 15.5px;
 position: relative;
}

.task__close:before {
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 content: '';
 right: 6px;
 top: 3px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 width: 5px;
 height: 10px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(128,128,128,0.8);
 border-right: 1px solid rgba(128,128,128,0.8);
 opacity: 0;
 transition: .2s linear opacity;
}

.task__close:hover {
 background-color: rgba(128,128,128,0.2);
 cursor: pointer;
}

.task__close:hover:before {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

 <section class="section">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="spheres">
    <div class="sphere health">
     <div class="svg__icon">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148838.svg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="sphere__title">
      Здоровье
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sphere intelligence">
     <div class="svg__icon">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1491/1491214.svg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="sphere__title">
      Развитие
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sphere sociality">
     <div class="svg__icon">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/1078/1078011.svg" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="sphere__title">
      Отношения
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>  <!-- .spheres -->
  </div> <!-- .container -->

  <div class="container fluid">
   <div class="add">
    <div class="add__title">
     Добавить задачу
    </div>
    <div class="add__input-wrapper">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Бег 1 км" class="add__input">
     <div class="add__button"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- .container.fluid -->

  <div class="container">
   <div class="tasks">
    <div class="task" data-id="0" data-listener='false'>
     <div class="task__close"></div>
     Моя первая задача
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> <!-- .container -->
 
 </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Учитывая что localStorage умеет хранить только строки вам всё равно придётся городить какой-то код для получения объектов из строки. Учитывая что простейший вариант это JSON.parse, я бы остановился на простых объектах. Усложнить всегда успеете

Comment: Просто я думал, что, если я хочу, с помощью функции класса удалять и записывать информацию, а с объектом вроде как нужно просто функции использовать. Хотя я не понимаю как это всё устроено, в объектах же методы есть, которые можно вызвать

Comment: Это вкусовщина и есть разные подходы  плюсы и минусы есть у обоих вариантов. Поскольку это очередной тудулист, я полагаю что это просто учебная работа, так определитесь какой подход вы хотите изучить и сделайте на нём

Comment: Почему именно localStorage, а не БД для такой не простой задачи?

Comment: @НиколайГабараев я хочу пользоваться таким todo листом и не платить за хостинг :D, сам задачник будет на гитхабе, может и другим он будет прикольным

Comment: `localStorage` имеет ограничения по длине строки и объему в, кажется 10Мб.  Не платить за хостинг? Ну запустите любой локальный веб-сервер и сделайте нормальный ТуДуЛист.

Comment: @НиколайГабараев я имел ввиду, что хочу пользоваться им с телефона, заходя на свой сайт, который будет храниться на github, а на github нельзя запускать серверный код

Comment: как-то....мудрено слишком.... =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` сохраняет только строки. Вам нужно будет пропускать Ваши объекты через `JSON.stringify` перед передачей их в `setItem` и через `JSON.parse` - на обратном пути.

Таким образом, не имеет значения простой ли у Вас объект, созданный `{}`, или объект класса.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Исходите из того, что обратно Вы получите объект **с** Вашими данными и **без** Ваших методов.

Comment: Ну почему же, объект класса сложнее «оживлять». В смысле придётся писать дополнительный код или брать готовые библиотеки (т.е. опять же дополнительный код)

Comment: Я вообще ожидал услышать ответ типа: объекты лучше использовать, потому что вы можете сделать то-то, а классы заставляют вас делать то-то.

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, какие объекты вы хотите использовать, если в локальном хранилище браузера можно хранить только строки.

Comment: @And , я думаю использовать объект, в котором будет массив из объектов, в которых будет содержатся информация